# I have installed @fortawesome/react-fontawesome via Yarn. How do I use the font in SCSS?

Tags: reactjs, sass, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to take the carousel from this: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-kit-react?partner=104080
and add it to my own react project. However, the slick-prev and slick-next buttons aren't displaying properly. I took a look at the SCSS that came with the kit and it looks like this:

```css
.slick-prev {
  left: 0;
  &::before {
    content: "\f053";
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.slick-next {
  right: 0;
  &::before {
    content: "\f054";
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

and I see that they have content that is displayed with the "Font Awesome 5" family, so I've been trying to install that in my project. I used the command `yarn add @fortawesome/react-fontawesome`, most of the things I found dealt with adding Icon components to React though, when I want to be able to use the font in CSS. What are the next steps to import this package as a font?

For my React Component, it looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import Carousel from 'react-slick'

import "../styles/scss/carousel.scss";

const SectionCarousel = () => {
    const settings = {
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true
    };

    const image1 = 'https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-react/static/media/bg.e5241971.jpg'
    const image2 = 'https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-react/static/media/bg2.84378183.jpg'
    const image3 = 'https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-react/static/media/bg3.e76de24b.jpg'

    return (
        <Carousel {...settings}>
            <img src={image1} alt="First slide" className="slick-image" />
            <img src={image2} alt="Second slide" className="slick-image" />
            <img src={image3} alt="Third slide" className="slick-image" />
        </Carousel>
    )
}

export default SectionCarousel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Slick Carousel, you have to import the needed CSS. Like this. [SLICK](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick)

```
!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.9.0/slick/slick.css"/>
<!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.9.0/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
```

The `font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;` in the slick btn css is used, because it's not with react-fontawesome. Btw. there is also a react port of slick carousel [HERE](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick)

To use Font Awesome in react, you have to install a couple of things. The details are [HERE](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome).

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
yarn add @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
yarn add @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Then use it like this

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const element = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />

ReactDOM.render(element, document.body)
```

Comment: Actually, I *am* using the react port of slick carousel, I added my react component code to the body of my question. As for using he FontAwesomeIcon, I don't see in the React component where I can add FontAwesomeIcon other than in the CSS. So, can I just use an import statement for the css things you mentioned and use them in my scss after?

Comment: did you also install slick-carousel for css and font in your project?

```
npm install slick-carousel
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

Comment: ahh now I understand. :) You are trying to replicate this https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-react/#/?

Comment: Just add the CSS for fontawesome
`<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">` in your CSS.

Comment: Can I do something like `@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css")` and `@import ulr("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css"`?

Comment: you could add it to the index.html in the public folder. or make a css file and import it like `import './nameofthecss.css'

Comment: Cool it worked! Thanks for all your help @Mario. I used the `import` syntax in my SCSS file so I could keep all that logic together.